# foreach loop with if statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, foreach

I'm running a query to have two columns in an html table.

```
 c.course_unit  
 m.score
```

In the m.score column, i want to do an if statement so that a point is awarded according to a certain range of the score. e.g

```
if ($row['m.score']  >= 70) {
point = 5;
 }
```

Then use each point awarded for each row multiplied with it's corresponding values in the other column i.e (c.course_unit).

This is what i've been able to come up with so far, and IT'S NOT EVEN CLOSE TO IT.

I'll  most appreciate you sincere help.
Thank you.

```
$grade_point = 0 ;
while ($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        if ($value >= 70) {
            $value['m.score'] = 5;
        }
        if ( $value['m.score'] >= 60 && $value['m.score']<= 69 ) {
            $value['m.score'] = 4;
        }
        if ( $value['m.score'] >= 50 && $value['m.score']<= 59 ) {
            $value['m.score'] = 3;
        }
        if ( $value['m.score'] >= 45 && $value['m.score']<= 49 ) {
            $value['m.score'] = 2;
        }
        if ( $value['m.score'] >=40 && $value['m.score']<= 45 ) {
            $value['m.score'] = 1;
        }
        if ($value['m.score'] < 40) {
            $value['m.score'] = 0;
        }

        $grade_point += $value['m.score'] * $value['c.course_unit'];
        echo "$grade_point";
    }
}
```

Comment: I reformatted the code for you this time. Please try and make the code a bit more readable in the future :)

Comment: Are you familiar with [`elseif` statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)?

Comment: I did 
    var_dump($row);
 
and it gave
 me the 2 dimensional array in 24 places. NOTE: I have 12
 rows generated from the query

Comment: @ruakh yes i am but it not working for me in this code. Thanks

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi: so, any thoughts?

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi: What do you mean, it's not working for you in that code? That code doesn't even use it!

Comment: You need to remove the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just remove the foreach loop. Its iterating through your fields.**

Here is the complete code that should work. I also change some variable name to fix it.

```
$grade_point = 0;
while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) {
    $marks = intval($row8['score']);
    if ($marks >= 70) {
        $score = 5;
    } elseif ($marks >= 60) {
        $score = 4;
    } elseif ($marks >= 50) {
        $score = 3;
    } elseif ($marks >= 45) {
        $score = 2;
    } elseif ($marks >= 40) {
        $score = 1;
    } else{
        $score = 0;
    }
    $grade_point+= $score * intval($row8['course_unit']);
    echo $grade_point;
}
```

**Note.**

1. For score 1 range should be from 40 to 44 (NOT 45) inclusively.
2. MySql result does not contain table alias in result set. So there is no 'm.score' Its just plain 'score'. (*Thanks to zerkms*)
3. Using `elseif` code can be reduced. (*Thanks to zerkms*)

Comment: oh yes, but it still doesn't solve the main issue - there is no `m.score` item in the array, but `score`. And probably you would better go with `elseif`

Comment: So fix first condition and change to `elsif` and this answer would deserve to be an *answer* ;-) Oh, and remove double quotes around `$grade_point`

Comment: Thanks for the code. The errors have removed but i'm getting " 0 " in 12 places. Thats the numbe of rows i have in the table.

Comment: When i ran you updated code i got a single 0 (zero). I also have a boolean false when i did var_dump($row)

Comment: `var_dump($row)` should be false after the while loop finishes. What is the value of `course_unit` column?

Comment: Course_unit : 4 1 1 2 2 2 0 5 4 1 3 1

The score for all of the is 56 that's a C with $score = 3

Comment: The 0 i'm getting is taking it's value from    $grade_point = 0 ;

when i change it's value the final result also takes that value i change 
$grade_point  to

Comment: Can i give a link to pastebin.com. It wont look okay here?

Comment: Yes. Sure. You can use pastie.org too.

Comment: You have used wrong variable `$row` in ` $score * $row['course_unit'];` and in `($row['score'] >= 70)`. it should be `$row8`

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. But still now showing correctly. Same  0  showing

Comment: Could you run this while loop and paste the result `while($row8=mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)){var_dump($row8);}`

Comment: `while($row8=mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)){var_dump($row8);}` does not shows up anything? `var_dump` always prints. Are you sure? did you check it properly? May be you should check the html source as well.

Comment: Nothing shows up if the while loop is placed at the end of the script, but a two dimensional array

 array
        'course_unit' => string '2' (lenght=1)
        'score' => string '56' (lenght=2)

these showed up 12 i.e the munber of rows. With the course_unit change according to the value.

Comment: Contd... When the while loop is move above the one before the last. It showed that array i sent to you.

Comment: Where else could the problem be be coming from? Because it's not printing anything apart from zero!

Comment: I've cleared cache and sessions several times, but it's still not showing apart from zero.

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer. Test it again. Also remove the while loop that contains `var_dump`.

Comment: @shiplu ... Thanks for the code, now it's showing the numbers and adding cummulatively and also displaying the previous sum. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should fix your conditions. a score of 45 for example, will be true in both if conditions:

```
if  ( $value['m.score'] >= 45  && $value['m.score']<= 49 ){
            $value['m.score'] = 2 ;}
if  ( $value['m.score'] >=40   && $value['m.score']<= 45 ){
            $value['m.score'] = 1 ;}
```

also, your first condition doesn't have a key... just $value instead of $value['m.score']

...and since you're using $value['m.score'] to store your point...the last condition will always be true. Your m.score will eventually always be 0

Comment: Thanks i fixed the issues you ponited out, but still to achieving my aim. I did a 

      var_dump($row); 

and it gave me the 2 dimensional array in 24 places. 

NOTE: I have 12 rows generated from the query

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi: and now it's time to see what `var_dump` returns and start comparing what you have and what you think you have

Comment: I'm getting a boolean false now that i run var_dump($row);

Comment: Thanks for the code, now it's showing
the numbers and adding cummulatively and also
 displaying the previous sum. But i'm looking for a final answer (INT).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplefy it with a fall-though:

```
<?php 

$grade_point = 0 ;
while ($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $mscore = $value['m.score'];
        $res;

        if ( $mscore < 40) {
            $res = 0;
        }
        if ( $mscore <= 45 ) {
            $res = 1;
        }
        if ( $mscore <= 49 ) {
            $res = 2;
        }  
        if ( $mscore <= 59 ) {
            $res = 3;
        }
        if ( $mscore <= 69 ) {
            $res = 4;
        }
        if ($mscore >= 70) {
            $res = 5;
        }

        $grade_point += $res * $value['c.course_unit'];
        echo "$grade_point";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, now it's showing
the numbers and adding cummulatively and also
 displaying the previous sum. And i'm looking to have a final answer (INT).
 Thanks